# Why is this code an infinite loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, infinite-loop

Before completing this code, I just tested it by mistake and realized that it will not stop:

```
$var = "any"; 
for ($i=1; $i < 2; $i++){ 
    $var.$i = "any"; 
}
```

Why does this produce an infinite loop? And why doesn't PHP produce an error?

Comment: Don't walk.  Run from PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a simple test :

```
echo $i;
 $var.$i = "any";
var_dump($var);
```

Result :

```
1string(3) "any"
anzstring(3) "any"
```

So $i get transformed to "anz" and doesn't pass the validation to get out of the loop.

$var.$i = "any"; is not really correct, i don't know what you are trying to do, but if you want to fill and array you should do something more like :

```
$var = array();
for ($i=1; $i < 2; $i++){ 
 $var[] = "any";
}
```

If you want to change your string letter by letter :

```
$var = "any";
    for ($i=1; $i < 2; $i++){ 
     $var[$i] = "a"; // asign a new letter to the string at the $i position
    }
```

Comment: thanks morsok, I knew these, I just wonder why PHP not produce any error, if this `$var.$i` not valid then why PHP executes?

Comment: Strictly speaking it's valid, the behavior is simply not what you expect. Internally i can't tell you exactly what it does, but it seems to change $i to the string "any" with the last letter being added the value of $i making 'y' go 'z', and this is always < 2 hense it's goes to an infinite loop.

Comment: @Skippy But I don't see any `z` here, ok, can you please explain what is `z`?

Comment: ok any way, thanks for your attention, I hope he decide if its z or y

Comment: It's a 'z', it didn't add space to the debug sorry about that, you should read the debug as : echo $i = "anz" var_dump($var) = ....

Answer (score 2):

When you do the following `$var.$i = 'any'` you set the `$i` variable and the `$var` variable.
So the the loop never stop running because `var_dump($i < 1)` returns true.

```
$var = 'var';
$i = 1;
$var.$i = 'var';

var_dump($i);
```

Returns `string(3) "var"`.

This loop will never stop because $i is always reset to 'var', which is smaller than 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect `$var.$i = "any";` because this expression is equivalent to:

```
 $var.($i = "any");
```

Which assigns `$i` to new value, therefore the condition of which the while loops checks will always be true.

Comment: I knew that, what is incorrect? why makes the loop go for Infinity!

Answer (score 0):

PHP5.4+.

You will get 'anz' result, after $i++, when $i == 'any'.
$i == 'any', after assignment and that is, actually, what it should get.
Trick is in "$i='any'" part of line. Even when "=" has lower precedence then ".", why do you think that it shouldn't put 'any' inside $i?

Try this instead:

```
$var = "any"; 
for ($i=1; $i < 2; $i++){ 
 $i.$var = "anything";
}
```

And your loop will work. And $var will get "anything" value. This doesn't look like a bug. Just unexpected behaviour for somebody.