# Why is it assigning value to $b? It should not as per operator precedence rule

Tags: php, variables, operators, operator-precedence

I was trying to answer [Why is this code an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856152/why-is-this-code-an-infinite-loop)

There I thought the issue could be because of operations precedence, but when I checked http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php , `.` has more precedence than `=`

so I tried the following code :

```
 $a.$b = "test";

 echo $a;
 echo $b;
```

and I got undefined variable `a` and `test` which means it is assigning value to $b, How is it assigning value to $b (Should not as per operations precedence)

Comment: Can you reference the operator precedence rule in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is clearly stated [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

> Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: `if (!$a = foo())`, in which case the return value of `foo()` is put into `$a`.

Expanding on [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17857388/164998), since you can't assign to an expression, the `=` takes precedence and the interpreter *sees* the following statement:

```
$a.($b = "test");
```

So they become two separate expressions, each following their own precedence. And therefore `test` is assigned to `$b`.

To prove this, add another assignment:

```
$a = 'my ';
$c = $a.$b = "test";

var_dump($a); // string(3) "my "
var_dump($b); // string(4) "test"
var_dump($c); // string(7) "my test"
```

Comment: Nice find. One of the things that one doesn't know because "no sane programmer would write code like that, so just don't think about it". :-) +1

Comment: Yes, I too file such questions under *Who Cares*. Reserved for lame interviews or those that wish to show off. However, it was the first question I saw today and I got sucked in.

Answer (score 3):

This does not make sense:

```
($a.$b) = "test"; // you can't assign to the result of an expression
```

This does:

```
$a.($b = "test");
```

Without going deeper than this, I believe the PHP compiler interprets the code as if you had written the latter because "that would work".

<strike>It wouldn't be the first time that the PHP parser's deficiencies "bleed through" and have surprising effects on the code.</strike>

**Update:** Turns out that [this is not a bug, it's a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17857531/50079).

Comment: That feels right but is there a language spec to back that up?

Comment: @Joe: There is no language spec for PHP, it's a free for all -- that's what I 'm trying to express. In language with a proper grammar and a spec this would be a compilation error.

Comment: But then what about the operator precedence rule ?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra: Precedence works fine, for example `printf($a = $b.'foo')` assigns `$b.'foo'` to `$a` before calling `printf`. I am fairly confident that this is just one of the corner cases where stuff breaks down because PHP.